# Nvidia digits object detection own dataset

Tags: object-detection, nvidia-digits

According to information on the Nvidia website Digits uses datatasets in Kitti format. Is there possibilty in Digits or in external application to prepare such dataset or I will have to write it on my own? 
I would like to simply draw bounding boxes on the displayed image and then have it converted to txt appropiate txt file. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use one of the available solutions for bounding box annotations eg. [RectLabel](https://rectlabel.com/), save the annotations in Pascal VOC format and then transform it to Kitti using one of the freely available converters, eg: [VOD Converter](https://github.com/umautobots/vod-converter)